# understand the relationship between CPUs and process

Tags: python, ubuntu, cpu-usage

I run a piece of python code in my machine, which has 4 CPUs. The CPUs status is like the following screenshot

[image: CPUs status]

As we can see, the first four PIDs have the value CPU% of more than 90%, and the 1st PID even achieve almost 400%. I am therefore confused with two questions:

Q1- No parallelization technique was used in this piece of code. Why would this non-parallel python code calls four CPUs instead of just one single CPU?

Q2-What's the relationship among the first four `PID 619, 663, 664, 665`? Does each of them correspond to each of my CPUs?

Comment: An offtopic side question: How can get a process a value of 400%? I thought, 100% is maximum value of cpu resources.

Answer (score 2):

The code is automatically run on all cpus from factory settings but you can tell the system just to use 1/2/3 cpus .
You used `htop` htop adds all cpus together, thats why you got 400% cpu resources